# help with C string i/o

Tags: c

Reads through a .txt file and puts all chars that pass isalpha() in a char array.  for spaces it puts \0, so the characters in the array are separated by strings.  This works.

I need help with the second part.  I need to read a string that the user inputs (lets call it the target string), find all instances of the target string in the char array, and then for each instance: 
1. print the 5 words before the target string
2. print the target string itself
3. and print the 5 words after the target string

I can't figure it out, i'm new to C in general, and I find this i/o really difficult after coming from Java.  Any help would be appreciated, here's the code I have right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
  FILE *inFile;
  char ch, ch1;
  int i, j;
  int arrayPointer = 0;

  char wordArray [150000];
  for (i = 0; i < 150000; i++)
    wordArray [i] = ' ';

  /* Reading .txt, strip punctuation, conver to lowercase, add char to array */
  void extern exit(int);
  if(argc > 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: fread <filename>\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  ch = fgetc(inFile);

  while (ch != EOF) {
    if(isalpha(ch)) {
      wordArray [arrayPointer] = tolower(ch);
      arrayPointer++;
    }
    else if (isalpha(ch1)) {
      wordArray [arrayPointer] = '\0';
      arrayPointer++;
    }

    ch1 = ch;
    ch = fgetc(inFile);
  }

  fclose;

  /* Getting the target word from the user */
  char str [20];

  do {
    printf("Enter a word, or type \"zzz\" to quit: ");
    scanf ("%s", str);

    char* pch;
    pch = strstr(wordArray, str);

    printf("Found at %d\n", pch - wordArray + 1);
    pch = strstr(pch + 1, str);
  } while (pch != NULL);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your program? What do you expect your code to do and what does it do differently?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here, but the one that is probably tripping you up the most is the use of `strstr` as you've got it.  Both parameters are strings; the first is the haystack, and the second is the needle.  The definition of a C string is (basically) a sequence of characters terminated by '\0'.  Take a look at how you've constructed your `wordArray`; it's effectively a series of strings one right after the other.  So when you are using `strstr` the first time, you are only ever looking at the first string.

I realize this isn't the entire answer you are looking for, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.  You may want to consider building up an array of `char *` that points into your `wordArray` at each word.  Iterate over that new array checking for the string the user is looking for.  If you find it, you now have an index you can work backwards and forwards from.